# What is Octave's alternative to MATLAB's dmod?

Tags: matlab, octave, scilab

My code in MATLAB:

```
M = 8; % количество уровней манипуляции        (# levels of manipulation)
sy = 0:M-1; % передаваемые символы             (passable signals)
Fd = 1; % символьная скорость                  (symbolic velocity)
Fc = 4; % несущая частота                      (carrying frequency)
FsFd = 40; % отношение Fs / Fd                 (Fs / Fd ratio)
Fs = Fd * FsFd; % частота дискретизации        (Discretization frequency)
% формируем АМн-сигнал                         (Forming the AM signal)
[s_ask, t] = dmod(sy, Fc, Fd, Fs, 'ask', M);
plot(t, s_ask)
grid on
```

There is no such function as `dmod` in octave, but `demodmap` or `ammod` do exist. Which one should I use instead?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is English-only. Whilst that technically does not uphold for in-code comments, it does mean that comments in Russian are of no use to most of the people here. There's [ru.SO] in case you want to ask your full question in Russian.

Comment: Note that `dmod` has been [removed from Matlab R2012a](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=dmod&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15864571/4183191